# Base de datos con sql server y c# win forms

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, linq

Hola amigos miren tengo un base de datos como la de la figura y la administro desde un aplicación en c# windows forms

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que tengo es con las tablas intermedias (pruebasPreguntas y preguntasOpciones). Al momento de crear una entrada de alguna otra tabla no se reflejan esos cambios en estas tablas.

Es decir puedo crear pruebas, preguntas, y opciones pero no existe las asociaciones en las tablas intermedias.

Los metodos insert declarados en Visual Studio son muy parecidos unos de otros..aqui dejo un ejemplo

```
public void Ingresar(String descripcion)
    {//metodo para registrar pregunta en base
        Pregunta nuevaPregunta = new Pregunta();
        nuevaPregunta.descripcion = descripcion;
        mibase.preguntas.InsertOnSubmit(nuevaPregunta);//guardar en preguntas valores ingresados
        mibase.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

y así es como lo invoco desde un botón

```
new Pregunta().Ingresar(txtTituloPregunta.Text);
```

Alguna idea para registrar las relaciones en las tablas intermedias

Comment: Estás utilizando Entity Framework?

Comment: Me pasó algo muy similar una vez y la solución un poco burda que encontré fue agregar a cada tabla intermedia un tercer campo DateTime que guardaba un simple DateTime.Now; no podría explicar el porqué de esa anómala solución porque no la recuerdo bien =/

Comment: Prueba a realizar un 

    mibase.SaveChanges();

para ver la excepción y si los datos del DataContext siguen siendo coherentes...

Además desde linq puedes utilizar acceso a las tablas relacionadas haciendo     

    tabla1.tabla2.valor4 = miValor.ToString();

Siempre que tengas en tu modelo importadas las relaciones.